# NoMethodError in CustomersController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

The error:

> undefined method `customers' for nil:NilClass
>
> app/controllers/customers_controller.rb:5:in `index'

Regarding to the documentation the method below will be available when the relations are set. But the controller just throw out the error. Any Ideas or suggestions?

```
def index
    @customers = @current_user.customers

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @customers }
    end
  end
```

This is my simple customers model:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :customerID, :first_name, :phone, :surname
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And my user model, mainly generated from devise.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :role_ids, :as => :admin
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me


  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, :case_sensitive => false

  has_many :customers

end
```

Thats the index.erb

```
<% @customers.each do |customer| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= customer.customerID %></td>
    <td><%= customer.surname %></td>
    <td><%= customer.first_name %></td>
    <td><%= customer.phone %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', customer %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_customer_path(customer) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', customer, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Where are you setting `@current_user`? The error indicates that it's `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object @current_user doesn't look like it's been properly instantiated. Since you are trying to call methods off an instance of your User model, you will need to properly instantiate the object in memory first.

If I remember right, the helper method for a devise current user session is 'current_user' without the '@'.

Comment: if i remove the @ I get `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: customers.user_id: SELECT "customers".* FROM "customers"  WHERE "customers"."user_id" = 3`

Comment: I'd recommend some tests that verify your model associations are working. The new error is telling you that it is trying to find customers with a user_id of 3, but the user_id field on the customers table doesn't exist. You will need to add a user_id field to your customers table. Removing the '@' is moving you in the right direction.

Comment: yeah that what i suspected... I did a migration to add the `user_id` column... now im back to `undefined method `customers' for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set @current_user to its right value before you can use it in your controller actions. In Devise you typically add a before filter to all controllers that are restricted to logged in users. That is:

```
before_filter :autenticate_user!
```

That will set @current_user to the logged in user.